# What is axiomatic method? Does it mean giving definitions beforehand and then using them in the proofs?

Tags: probability, geometry, terminology

Also, what does axiomatic approach to probability mean? Does it mean a similar thing?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough question, specially for all the philosophy of mathematics in between. The Axiomatic Method is the position taken by David Hilbert (1862-1943) concerning the Foundations of Mathematics. The main idea is similar to that used by Euclid in Geometry: to stablish some primitive concepts, and a number of axioms that rules the relationship among those primitive concepts; we obtain the proposition of our theory using some specific rules of logic.
The example of Geometry: the primitive concepts are "line", "point" and "plane", "lies on, contains", "between" and "congruent"; Hilbert propose in 1899 20 axioms for plane geometry. This is a remarkable book in the History of Mathematics: "Grundlagen der Geometrie" (The Foundations of Geometry). Right now, there are many axiomatic systems: Set Theory, Real Analysis, Probability....
But in the 30's Gödel show a major problem inside the theory of the axiomatic method: "Gödel's Icompleteness Theorem", but that's another story.